# ios how to setup a scrollview with autolayout?

Tags: ios, scrollview, autolayout

i'm tying to programmatically create a `scrollView` that will show a description.

my hierarchy is probably going to be like this:

```
->root View  
--->scroll View  
----->content View  
------->Label1  
------->Label2
------->Label3
```

here is an image that shows the structure of the app:

[image]

this is the code so far, i get what i want except that now **i need to include all this inside a `scrollView`** (that will scroll only vertically).
i tried many different things but i still don't get how to do it.

```
UIView *contentView = [UIView autolayoutView];
contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
[self.view addSubview:contentView];
NSDictionary *views2 = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(contentView);
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[contentView]|" options:0 metrics:0 views:views2]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[contentView]" options:0 metrics:0 views:views2]];

UILabel *one = [UILabel autolayoutView];
UILabel *two = [UILabel autolayoutView];
UILabel *three = [UILabel autolayoutView];
for(UILabel *label in @[one,two,three]){
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    label.text = @"fjeif\njeif\noesjf\nfjeif\njeif\noesjf\nfjeif\njeif\noesjf\nosfj";
    label.numberOfLines = 0;
    [contentView addSubview:label];
}
NSDictionary *views3 = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(one,two,three);
[contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-[one]-|" options:0 metrics:0 views:views3]];
[contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[one(two)]-[two(three)]-[three]-|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllLeft | NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterX metrics:0 views:views3]];
```

thanks, sorry if i didn't describe my problem well enough, i'm in a hurry. looking at the image should be enough to understand though.

Comment: Why don't u use UITableview instead??

Comment: If you are using storyboard then select that particular UIViewController and just say add missing constraints from resolve auto layout issues.

Comment: I might use a tableview but there has to be a way to do it with a scollview... I'm only using storyboards to setup the root contollers, almost everything else is done programmatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem though I set all constraints from XIB. You can do like this.

Add leading edge, trailing edge, top space and bottom space constraints to labels with respect to container view. Then you can add these same constraints to container view with respect to scrollView. Do the same exercise for scrollView.
You just need to add one more constraint (Horizontally center in container view constraint)to container view.
Hope this will help you.

Comment: thanks, i tried with the table as suggested by [Jayaprada](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2721287/jayaprada) and i still found problems (calculating the cell's heights) but at the end i managed to get it to work and now i think i'll stick to that solution.  
thanks anyway for the comment :)